# iOS - way to force Xcode's debugger to work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa

One of the most annoying bugs of Xcode is that some objects vanish from the debugging window when you most need them. Is there a way to force Xcode to always show all objects?

thanks.

Comment: "force Xcode's debugger to work" - maybe a whip?

Comment: I know. Xcode 4.x stinks infinity squared plus 1

Comment: you hate it more than I do and my hate is infinite.

Comment: I made my best hating Xcode, but apparently you're better at it. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to see the content of an object, I simply type "po objectName" in the debug console. If it's a primitive you want to examine, then use "p variableName".

Example: "po self"

I know it doesn't answer your question, but it's a pretty good work-around.

Comment: thanks. That helps a lot!!!! No need to say I hate Xcode 4.x with passion. Thanks.

Comment: Also try typing `help` in the debug console -- there's a whole help system (and it is arguably better than the documentation at this point.)